# What is the jquery selector for frame contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frame, frameset

What is the jQuery selector I need to access **username** from within **main.html**?  The alert should say "Bob".

**main.html**

```
<head>
<script>
    alert(username);  // *** not working ***
</script>
</head>

<frameset> 
  <frame name="left" src="left.html">
  <frameset> 
    <frame name="top" src="top.html">
    <frame name="right" src="right.html">
  </frameset>
</frameset>
```

**right.html**

```
<head>
<script>
    var username = 'Bob';
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `contentWindow` property.

Example:

```
document.getElementById('frame_id').contentWindow.$('#' + idOfElementInFrame);
```

Note: this works for `iframe` tags. It should work for `frame` tags as well, but given that the `frame` tag is deprecated, you could have issues.

Comment: Thanks Dhiviya.  How can I access a javascript variable in the contentWindow header instead of a DOM element by id?

Comment: @p1xelarchitect, since username has global scope in the contentWindow, you should be able to get it using contentWindow.username (provided the document head has already executed in the frame, when you're accessing the variable).

Comment: I found I had to obtain the `document` property of the `contentWindow` property to get it to work w. `<frame>`s. This is w. Firefox 65.0 and jQuery 3.3.1. For example, `$("a", document.getElementsByTagName("frame")[0].contentWindow.document)` to select the links inside the frame.

Answer (score 1):

```
There is an example:
(1)mainpage:

    <html>
    <script>
    function show(){
      var winleft = window.frames["left"];
      alert(winleft.username);
    }
    </script>
    <frameset cols="25%,50%,25%">
      <frame src="left.html" name="left">
      <frame src="left.html" name="middle">
      <frame src="left.html" name="right">
    </frameset>

    </html>

(2)left.html

<head>
<script>
    var username = 'Bob';
</script>
</head>
```

(3)why?
Every frame has its own Object "window",
 you should get the "window" object of the frame["left"],and the variable    "username" is the proterty of the frame["left"]'s window(**winleft**) object.so,you can get the value of username.